# Package xxx requires unavailable shared library - Maps API

Tags: api-key

I am working with a sample app that uses the Maps API and getting the following error:

```
Package xxx requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
```

I have obtained a Maps API key from my debug certificate fingerprint and inserted it into my main xml file thusly:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapmain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="lotsoflettersandnumbers" />
```

I have also loaded the maps jar file onto my device. What am I doing wrong or not doing right? What else do you need to know to help answer this question?

I tried this on another device (Android 2.3; the device getting the error is 2.1) and it works. One thing I noticed is that on the 2.1 device, the permissions for the maps.jar file are -rwxrwxrwx, and on the 2.3 device they are -rw-r--r--. Could that be contributing to the error?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I was missing the file /system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml, which is also required. FWIW, I am working with a ruggedized Android device that does not come with the google maps jar or xml files on it. That's why I had to add them myself.

Comment: @Abhi seriously man! He should have given the solution too not just the explanation! :(